# How to put Current time in form using php and mysql?. I want to put current time in these fields Please help me

Tags: php

I want to insert current time in the textbox field in php form. How should I insert it . Please help me. I am new to php and mysql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some simple google would ve solved it.

```
<input type="text" name="time" value="<?php echo date('H:i:s')?>">
```

for time manual
  http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" name="curr_time" value="<?php echo date('H:i:s')?>">
```

Comment: date('Y-m-d') if you want date